# Appharbor build error

Tags: appharbor

On attempting to build an MVC application on appharbor I'm consistently getting the following error -

> AfterBuild:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v
>   temp -p D:\temp\yjartxut.xdg\output_PublishedWebsites\groundstour 
>   ASPNETCOMPILER : error ASPRUNTIME: The current identity
>   (IP-0A7AA6EA\apphb3308801b5493433) does not have write access to
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files'.

I've searched the appharbor support forums but can't find a thread that deals with an error similar to the one above, could anyone shed any light on the error or what I could do to fix it?

Comment: We're seeing problems with view compilation for certain types of projects, disabling view compilation until that's fixed should get you builds through. We'll keep you posted.

Comment: @friism I just had the same issue. Disabling view compilation worked. Is there an update on this?

Comment: This is fixed now, sorry about the breakage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an AppHarbor-problem, and it should now be resolved.

(disclaimer, I'm co-founder of AppHarbor)

Comment: This is happening to me still.

Comment: @ElanHasson could you drop us a line with details at support@appharbor.com